# Download an Image file from web server using VC++ 9.0

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to code a VC++ 9 based console application which downloads an image from a webserver.

I have code which used to run in VC++ 6, but its giving lot of compilation errors in  VC++ 9.0.

I need code which compiles in VC++ 9.0 using MS Visual Studio 2008.

Also I need only win32 code and not MFC.

Comment: how do you expect anybody to help if you don't give any information? The least thing required is what is the type of errors you are getting.

Comment: what do you mean by "I need ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download something from the Web you could use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library. It doesn't use MFC.